# Extract a number from a string in Windows shell script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

i have a string like the  this the script file  hello-1234-something.  i need to get 1234 using batch file.  But the number 1234 is not same it keeps changing  I need to find the number in a string and take just the number out.   I am new to batchfile programming.  I wanted to do that in batch

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "teststring=abcDEFG1234ABSdefh"

FOR %%a IN (
    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
        ) DO (
    SET "teststring=!teststring:%%a=!"
)
ECHO %teststring%
```

Note: this doesn't work with special characters, eg.: `<>&|!^`

Answer (score 1):

If your string always has the form string-hyphen-number-hyphen-string (e.g. `foo-23-bar`, `some-205-orother`, …) you could do something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "string=foo-23-bar"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%n in ("%string%") do set "num=%%n"

echo %num%
```